# I don't understand struct.unpack

Tags: python, struct

With the next code:

```
shmem = mmap.mmap(0, 20, "MumbleLink", mmap.ACCESS_READ)
print("size: "+str(struct.calcsize("IL3f3f3f512s3f")))
print(struct.unpack("IL3f3f3f512s3f", shmem))
```

I get this output:

```
size: 568
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saelyth\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(struct.unpack("IL3f3f3f512s3f", shmem))
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 568
```

**Why does it tells me that it requires an object of length 568 if calcsize says it's already 568?**

Also, worth to mention that I had been googling (and checked [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html))  for an answer of what is *IL3f3f3f512s3f* or how can you create your own string to read memory of for example 1024, not 568, but so far I had no luck. A detailed answer on how that part of struct works would help, or point me in the right direction of how to understand how to calculate the string that I need to use to unpack shmem.

This is related to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874804/accessing-a-memory-mapped-file-using-python) question.

Comment: What version of Python? Py2 treats mmaps as strings, Py3 as bytearrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only check the size in output, that size is not available to your memory map. So change your first line to:

```
shmem = mmap.mmap(0, 568, "MumbleLink", mmap.ACCESS_READ);
```

Which matches the size of struct. If you want, you can get the size first, then create the memory map to match it (second parameter.)

Comment: You are right, I was running in circles wondering what was wrong with struct and I forgot the mmap part. Thank you.